# Is there a Digg Reader bookmarklet?

Tags: digg

And if there is, where can I find it? I realise there's a browser plugin, but I'm specifically trying to find a bookmarklet. One to allow me to add sites to Reader, rather than having to add them manually.

Comment: According to the blog, one is planned but they've not announced anything.

Answer (score 2):

You can use either AddThis or ShareThis bookmarklets which supports a Digg bookmarklet.

http://www.addthis.com/browser-extensions/bookmarklets
http://www.sharethis.com/features/download